# Does destroying cars in missions earn money from the car scrapyard?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Does destroying cars in missions help earn money from the car scrapyard? I'm trying to make a good bit of money and I need help.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question. Yes.

You get $150 per car destroyed. In a mission, free roaming, whatever. When you destroy a car anywhere in Los Santos the scrapyard will generate $150 of revenue.

Comment: That is only true if he has purchased the scrapyard, and only for the character that purchased it.

Comment: And only for singleplayer?

Comment: Yes, only for singleplayer.

Comment: How did I miss this :|